# Cron Job for Redmine Rake commands. Email processing

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron, rake, redmine

May be Stackoverlow Community can help me, cuz I'm out of ideas.

I have installed test Redmine with help of [this guide](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_30x_on_Ubuntu_1404_with_Apache2_Phusion_Passenger_MySQL_Subversion_and_Git_(Gitolite))

So, I have two users - "serveradminuser" and "redmine" (from guide)
Rake commands can be used only by user "redmine".

If I paste this code in terminal by redmine user

```
cd /opt/redmine/redmine; /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.0./bin/rake -f /opt/redmine/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=XX username=XX password=XX port=XX allow_override=all
```

and all is good.

I made this `crontab -u redmine -e` with this code:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /opt/redmine/redmine; /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.0./bin/rake -f /opt/redmine/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=XX username=XX password=XX port=XX allow_override=all
```

but nothing happens. Syslog didn't wrote nothing special.

I use Ubuntu Server 14.04.
Any ideas how can I make cron jobs running?

Answer (score 0):

Peronnaly for my cronjob in ruby I use [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler).

You can try it by adding this file in your config/initializer folder:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require 'rufus-scheduler'

load File.join(Rails.root, 'Rakefile')

ENV['host']='XX'
ENV['username']='XX'
ENV['password']='XX'
ENV['port']='XX'
ENV['allow_override']='all'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.interval '1m' do
  task = Rake.application['redmine:email:receive_imap']
  task.reenable
  task.invoke
end
```

Don't forget to add `gem 'rufus-scheduler'` in your Gemfile and bundle it.

Luc